# What does "homomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Context: In the book "New Thinking in School Mathematics" (p.67) Prof. Gustave Choquet suggests to implement groups, rings and fields in secondary school mathematics. He then proceeds to list precise topics. Among other things he says "Examples of group; ring of integers modulo $n$, homomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and of $R$ over $R/a\mathbb Z$".

He doesn't define what $R$ is (presumably an arbitrary ring that contains the ideal $a\mathbb Z$) but what baffles me is the choice of words: What is a homomorphism **over** something? I have heard of this phrasing in the context of algebras over rings for example but never in the context of homomorphisms.

What does or could this mean?

Comment: Since he is clearly intending to list very elementary topics, at a wild I guess I would say that in the first case he means "homomorphisms **from** $\mathbb Z$ **onto** $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$". And in the second case he means the same thing but with $R$ equal to the real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gustave Choquet was French. And in French, one of the translations of "sur" is "over", like in this sentence:

> des nuages sur les montagnes $\to$ clouds over the mountain

Thus it is very likely that the sentence "homomorphisme de $\Bbb{Z}$ sur $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$" has been translated by "homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ over $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$".

Comment: And perhaps the standard mathematical English translation would use "onto"?

Comment: @lee-mosher Of course, yes !

Comment: That indeed sounds very reasonable and is, in fact, what I had in mind in the first place (meaning the $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$ part, not the french one). Thanks for your answer!